# i'm trying to code an inventory list for BookStore but i cant seem to get it to pass through the params in Book class

Tags: java, bluej

```
- public class BookStore {
   private String storeName; 
   private Book[] inventory;  

   public BookStore(){
       inventory = new Book[1]; 

       inventory[0]  = new Book ((new Author(firstname,lastname,middle)), new Date(2015), "booktitle") ;


   }

public class Book {
   private static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Untitled";

   private Author author;
   private Date published;
   private String title;


   public Book(Author author, Date published, String title)
   {
       setAuthor(author);
       setDatePublished(published);
       setTitle(title);
   }

   }   {

   private String first;
   private String middle;
   private String last;
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: it doesn't allow me to compile

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I've taken the liberty of formatting you code in the question to make it more clear. The changes should be visible soon. Please update your question with the compilation error you are seeing.

Comment: inventory[0]  = new Book ((new Author(firstname,lastname,middle)), new Date(2015), "booktitle") ;

this doesn't go through the param in the book class and does not compile.

Comment: ok, so that is the line of code that you think the problem occurs at, but if it does not compile you should be given a reason why. Please post the output from the compiler that says what the error is.

Comment: Java compiler errors are mostly pretty straight-forward, but without giving us the actual error, wild guessing is the only thing we can do.

Comment: From what you've pasted above, the Author class doesn't seem to be declared at all, in fact the attributes of it are just hanging at the end of the code snippet in an odd looking block...is this all the code?

Comment: it says that the firstname - cannot find symbol - variable firstname

Comment: so the new book, initiates the list, then the first, last middle name will pass through the constructor of the Book class. then gets stored in the Name class first, middle, last.